# How was entropy understood before the development of statatistical thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, history

Now is common to talk about entropy as related to "disorder", mostly for non physicists. For physicists, entropy is related to the number of micro states allowed to a system. But what did "entropy" mean to people in the XIX century?

Before statistical thermodynamics, scientists and engineers used the concept of "entropy" to solve practical problems in thermodynamics. Did they also imagine entropy as related to disorder? did they relate it to something else?

Comment: This question belongs to [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com), no? Surely...

Answer (score 3):

Clausius invented the term *entropy* in 1865, which he understood as 'loss of movement of activity' i.e. energy (heat) losses. This is how engineers used (and continued to use) the concept, e.g. steam engine design, in the 19th century, even after Boltzmann introduced statistical thermodynamics in 1877.

Answer (score 2):

Before Clausius there was Sadi Carnot, who many consider the father of macro (as opposed to micro or statistical) thermodynamics.

Although I'm not aware of Carnot presenting the concept of entropy per se, his understanding of the maximum theoretical  efficiency of a heat engine operating in a cycle laid the ground work of it.

Then of course after Clausius we have Ludwig Boltzmann, the  father of statistical mechanics, and his famous equation $S=k$ log W.

Hope this helps.